# Extract links from html page

Tags: python, html

I am trying to fetch all movie/show netflix links from here http://netflixukvsusa.netflixable.com/2016/07/complete-alphabetical-list-k-sat-jul-9.html and also their country name. e.g from the page source, I want http://www.netflix.com/WiMovie/80048948, USA, etc. I have done the following. But it returns all links instead of the netflix ones I want. I am a little new to regex. How should I go about this?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen('http://netflixukvsusa.netflixable.com/2016/07/complete-alphabetical-list-k-sat-jul-9.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    ##reqlink = re.search('netflix',link.get('href'))
    ##if reqlink:
    print link.get('href')

for link in soup.findAll('img'):
    if link.get('alt') == 'UK' or link.get('alt') == 'USA':
        print link.get('alt')
```

If I uncomment the lines above, I get the following error:

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

What should I do?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
import requests

url = 'http://netflixukvsusa.netflixable.com/2016/07/complete-alphabetical-list-k-sat-jul-9.html'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
count = 1
title=[]
country=[]
for line in r.iter_lines():
    if count == 746:
        urllib2.urlopen('http://netflixukvsusa.netflixable.com/2016/07/complete-alphabetical-list-k-sat-jul-9.html')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(line)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('netflix')):
            title.append(link.get('href'))

        for link in soup.findAll('img'):
            print link.get('alt')
            country.append(link.get('alt'))

    count = count + 1

print len(title), len(country)
```

The previous error has been worked upon. Now the only thing to look for is films with multiple countries. How to get them together.
e.g. for 10.0 Earthquake, link = http://www.netflix.com/WiMovie/80049286, country = UK, USA.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified to a couple of *selects*:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://netflixukvsusa.netflixable.com/2016/07/complete-alphabetical-list-k-sat-jul-9.html'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

for a in soup.select("a[href*=netflix]"):
    print(a["href"])
```

And for the img:

```
co = {"UK", "USA"}
for img in soup.select("img[alt]"):
    if img["alt"] in co:
        print(img)
```

Comment: You're a saviour :)

Comment: Btw. I've answered it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question - it failed for links that didn't have an href value. So instead of a string you got `None`.

The following works:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen('http://netflixukvsusa.netflixable.com/2016/
07/complete-alphabetical-list-k-sat-jul-9.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    link_href = link.get('href')
    if link_href:  
        reqlink = re.search('netflix',link_href)       
        if reqlink:
            print link_href       

for link in soup.findAll('img'):
    if link.get('alt') == 'UK' or link.get('alt') == 'USA':
        print link.get('alt')
```

As for the second question, I would recommend having a dictionary between the movie to a list of countries that it appears in, then it would be easier to format it in a string the way you want.

Comment: Hey, I worked on the first one already. As mentioned in the edits. Can you look at the second code and tell me how to modify it to get the {'URL':url,'country':[...]} As the second loop runs through each img and not each table value, hence I cannot find all countries for a specific url and put  it into dictionary as you'd said.

Comment: Before adding to the dictionary check if the key already exists. If it does, append to the list, otherwise create a new list.

Comment: But, how do you loop through the two simultaneously- two being soup.findAll('a') and soup.findAll('img'), when they have different lengths?

Comment: And no where is there a grouping of the two together i.e. a particular Url is from a particular row/country hence this country is the right one for it. I hope you get what I'm asking.

Comment: You can iterate over the all the "tr" elements inside the "listings" table instead of separately iterating over all "a" and "img" elements in the page. Each "tr" has both the movie link and the countries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have an easier iterating through the listing rows and using a generator to assemble the data structure you're looking for (ignore the minor differences in my code, I'm using Python3):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://netflixukvsusa.netflixable.com/2016/07/' \
      'complete-alphabetical-list-k-sat-jul-9.html'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
rows = soup.select('span[class="listings"] tr')


def get_movie_info(rows):
    netflix_url_prefix = 'http://www.netflix.com/'
    for row in rows:
        link = row.find('a',
                        href=lambda href: href and netflix_url_prefix in href)
        if link is not None:
            link = link['href']
        countries = [img['alt'] for img in row('img', class_='flag')]
        yield link, countries


print('\n'.join(map(str, get_movie_info(rows))))
```

**Edit:** Or if you're looking for a dict instead of a list:

```
def get_movie_info(rows):
    output = {}
    netflix_url_prefix = 'http://www.netflix.com/'
    for row in rows:
        link = row.find('a',
                        href=lambda href: href and netflix_url_prefix in href)
        if link is not None:
            name = link.text
            link = link['href']
        countries = [img['alt'] for img in row('img', class_='flag')]
        output[name or 'some_default'] = {'link': link, 'countries': countries}
    return output


print('\n'.join(map(str, get_movie_info(rows).items())))
```

Comment: This doesn't give me all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'http://netflixukvsusa.netflixable.com/2016/07/complete-alphabetical-list-k-sat-jul-9.html'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
count = 1
final=[]
for line in r.iter_lines():
    if count == 746:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(line)
        for row in soup.findAll('tr'):
            url = row.find('a', href=re.compile('netflix'))
            if url:
                t=url.string
                u=url.get('href')
                one=[]
                for country in row.findAll('img'):
                    one.append(country.get('alt'))
                final.append({'Title':t,'Url':u,'Countries':one})
    count = count + 1
```

`final` is the final list.